# Create new vector from row index of two matching columns

Tags: r, match, subset, data-manipulation

I have a data frame:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)

b <- c(1,2,1,2,1,4)

c <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")

df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

What I want to do, is create another vector `d`, which contains the value of `c` in the row of `a` which matches each value of `b`

So my new vector would look like this:

```
d <- c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "D")
```

As an example, the final value of `b` is `4`, which matches with the 4th row of `a`, so the value of `d` is the 4th row of `c`, which is `"D"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If *a* and *b* are both lists with integer values you can use them directly.

```
d <- c[b[a]]
d
[1] "A" "B" "A" "B" "A" "D"
```

if *a* is a regular integer sequence along *c* you can simply call *c* from *b*.

```
c[b]
[1] "A" "B" "A" "B" "A" "D"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to convert to factor and use it as:

```
factor(a, labels = c)[b]
#[1] A B A B A D
```

**OR**

```
as.character(factor(a, labels = c)[b])
#[1] "A" "B" "A" "B" "A" "D"
```

**data**

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)

b <- c(1,2,1,2,1,4)

c <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
```